# Does the function have horizontal or vertical asymptotes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

So I'm analyzing some functions here and I need to determine whether or not they have horizontal or vertical asymptotes.  The equations are:

$f(x)=260$

$g(x)=1+24(0.9)^x$

$h(x)=f(x)/g(x)$

Now $f(x)$ I do not believe has asymptotes since it is linear.  $g(x)$ looks like by its graph that it could have either. $h(x)$ should not have a vertical asymptote but I am not sure if it has a horizontal asymptote.

If someone could help me with this, that'd be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right about $f(x)$: no asymptotes there.

For $g(x)$, given your tags, I'm not sure with you've been exposed to the concept of a limit. If you have, simply taking $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$ and you will find $g(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote $y=1$. If you, are unfamiliar with this concept, just remember that $g(x)$ is an exponential decay, so the $24(0.9)^x$ piece will decay to 0 as x gets very large. Therefore, ignoring the $24(0.9)^x$ piece, you find $g(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote $y=1$.

For $h(x)$, you can see it doesn't have a vertical asymptote because the denominator never is 0. Either using limits ($\lim_{x\to-\infty} h(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} h(x)$) or graphing over a sufficiently large window, you should be able to convince yourself that as $x$ grows very large (approaching  $+\infty$), $h(x)$ approaches 260 and as $x$ approaches $-\infty$, $h(x)$ approaches 0. Therefore, $h(x)$ has two horizontal asymptotes $y=0$ and $y=260$.

Comment: So to clarify, h(x) doesn't have a vertical asymptote, but it has a horizontal asymptote at y=0?

Comment: @Ash h(x) has no vertical asymptotes since the denominator (g(x)) never equals 0. h(x) has _two_ horizontal asymptotes: at y=0 and y=260